# Which is the more effiecient encapsulation for set

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been digging into WPF and MVVM lately, and I've seen many examples using an encapsulation method such as:

```
private string _firstName;
public string FirstName
{
    get {return _firstName;}
    set
    {
        if (value != _firstName;)
        {
            _firstName = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

So it does a quick comparison before setting the value in favor of the standard set and forget:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get {return _firstName;}
    set {_firstName = value;}
}
```

Is this method actually more efficient always or only when using MVVM?

Comment: I have only seen this in combination with `INotifyPropertyChanged` or similar mechanisms where you want to raise an event only if the value actually changed.

Comment: Yes it is used to avoid the property changed event being called unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

When doing MVVM in WPF, there is an additional step (that you omitted), which is to raise `PropertyChanged` in your setter.

The event invocation could be very expensive, so checking if the value has actually changed is worthwhile. In "normal" code, the expense of assignment is small, so the results would be far closer to "no effective difference".

Without running my own benchmarks, I would suspect that the difference in your two provided samples is negligible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  That makes perfect sense, especially when there are many items that need to be notified when a change occurs.  I can see how it could be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are almost the same, even if you repeat the assignment 1 million of times.

Nevertheless code isn't just about performance or business logic.

Code is about poetry so readability and maintainability are the finest art.

You'll see that the best piece of code is this

```
public string FirstName
{
    get {return _firstName;}
    set {_firstName = value;}
}
```

And most of the time the best piece of code will be the one I put bellow.

```
public string FirstName
{
    get;
    set;
}
```